# How to measure and capture a script’s execution time in DolphinDB?

Tags: time, execution-time, dolphindb

I’d like to measure and capture my script’s execution time and assign it to an variable. I tried to assign the return of function `timer` to variable a, but it raised an exception of “invalid expression”.

```
a = timer x=1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The exception is raised because `timer` is not a function but a procedure. It only prints a message that cannot be assigned to a variable. However, you can use function `evalTimer`, which returns a scalar that can be assigned to a variable.

To use function `evalTimer`, you can rewrite the statement block as a user-defined function. See [evalTimer — DolphinDB 1.3 documentation](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/e/evalTimer.html)

You can also check the syntax of a function with `syntax`:

```
syntax(evalTimer)
// evalTimer(funcs, [count=1])
```

**funcs**: the function(s) for which the execution time is measured

**count**: the number of times funcs will be executed. The default value is 1.

To measure the execution time of  function `foo`:

```
def foo(){
    x=1
}
a= evalTimer(foo,10);
print(a)
// output: 0.031341
```

In the above example, the code to be executed is encapsulated into a user-defined function `foo`. Then use function `evalTimer` to measure the time of running function `foo` 10 times, assign the result to variable a, and print it out.